# Different horizontal and vertical spaces between subfigures with tikz text and inset

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption, subfig

I am trying to insert a bunch of pictures of the same size (1416x1158). and inside of some subfigures, there is a zoomed-in picture. Also, I am adding captions using tikz node. But there is a problem, pictures have different spaces between each other.
[image]
It seems that adding inset somehow changes the effective width of the picture because I tried to add `\hspace{0}`, but it did not help me.
People, help me!
there is a code which I have used:

```
%\listfiles
\documentclass [review]{elsarticle} %review, draft

\usepackage{subcaption,fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %rescaling of tikz pics


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


% to border pictures
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.005pt}
\newcommand{\tmpframe}[1]{\fbox{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mw}{0.233\textwidth}
\newcommand{\maw}{1.0\linewidth}

\newcommand{\mysubfigure}[2]{
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\mw}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\maw, 
% height=\mah
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (O) at (0,0)
        {\tmpframe{\includegraphics[trim={0.5cm 0 0.5cm 0},clip,width=1.1\linewidth]{#1}}};
    \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (0,-1.2) {#2};
    \ifdefined\mycap
    \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (-1.6,-1.2) {\mycap};
    \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{0.0cm}%
}

\newcommand{\mysubfigureinset}[9]{
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mw}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=\maw, 
        % height=\mah
        }
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[inner sep=0pt] (O) at (0,0)
             {\tmpframe{\includegraphics[trim={0.5cm 0 0.5cm 0},clip,width=1.1\linewidth]{#1}}};
            \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (0,-1.2) {#2};
            \node[anchor=north east] at (#7,#8) {\tmpframe{\includegraphics[trim={#3 #4 #5 #6},clip,width={#9\linewidth}]{#1}}};
            \ifdefined\mycap
            \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (-1.6,-1.2) {\mycap};
            \fi
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.0cm}%
}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace{-0.0cm}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\mw}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=\maw, 
        % height=\mah
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (O) at (0,0)
            {\tmpframe{\includegraphics[trim={0.5cm 0 0.5cm 0},clip,width=1.1\linewidth]{pic.png}}};
            \draw[thick,->] (-1.35,0) -- (-1.35 + 0.35,0.4) node[pos=1, above] {$R_b$};
            \draw[thick,->] (-1.35,0) -- (-1.35 - 0.15,0.2) node[pos=1, below] {{${\scriptscriptstyle R_s}$}};
        \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (0,-1.2) {$t=0$};
        \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (-1.6,-1.2) {(a)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1cm}%
    % \mysubfigure{P/Moving_solid/BPM_t=0.png}{(a) $t=0$}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=0.4$}{740}{570}{580}{470}{2.15}{1.8}{0.31}
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=1.65$}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=2.25$}{610}{510}{680}{510}{2.15}{1.8}{0.35}
    % 
    \newcommand{\mycap}{(b)}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=1.5$}{950}{530}{300}{470}{-0.}{1.8}{0.48}
    \let\mycap\undefined
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=1.6$}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=1.65$}{1000}{510}{200}{450}{-0.}{1.8}{0.5}
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=2.25$}
    % 
    \newcommand{\mycap}{(c)}
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=1.65$}
    \let\mycap\undefined
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=1.68$}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=3.6$}{950}{510}{300}{510}{0.05}{1.8}{0.51}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=13.6$}{950}{510}{300}{510}{0.05}{1.8}{0.51}
    % 
    \newcommand{\mycap}{(d)}
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{(d) $t=1.5$}
    \let\mycap\undefined
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=1.65$}
    \mysubfigure{pic.png}{$t=2.25$}
    \mysubfigureinset{pic.png}{$t=15.6$}{1150}{510}{100}{510}{-0.}{1.8}{0.5}
    %
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:moving_ring}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Here is a original file.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Hello Jose! Thank you for your advice) I have added it

Comment: The answer was just moving a little bit inset picture to the center.